# Proving energy conservation from functional equations

Tags: physics, functional-equations

I am trying to prove that kinetic energy is conserved in a collision given that it is time reversible by putting this problem in terms of functional equations.

Consider a vector-valued function which must satisfy the following properties

$$f(m_1,m_2,\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2) = \mathbf{v}_1'$$
$$f(m_2,m_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{v}_1) = \mathbf{v}_2'$$
$$f(m_1,m_2,-\mathbf{v}_1',-\mathbf{v}_2') = -\mathbf{v}_1$$
$$f(m_2,m_1,-\mathbf{v}_2',-\mathbf{v}_1') = -\mathbf{v}_2$$
$$m_1\mathbf{v}_1+m_2\mathbf{v}_2=m_1\mathbf{v}_1'+m_2\mathbf{v}_2'$$
Then how does one prove that it must also satisfy the following relation?
$$m_1\mathbf{v}_1^2+m_2\mathbf{v}_2^2=m_1\mathbf{v}_1'^2+m_2\mathbf{v}_2'^2$$